# Should my company change the internal Root CA hash method from SHA-1 to SHA-2?

Tags: web-browser, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, sha

My company have a Root Certificate Authority which is installed on a Windows Server 2003 and uses SHA-1 as hash method.

We will migrate to Windows Server 2012.

Checking the root certificates of my browser I see that almost all Root CAs are using SHA-1 or below.

My questions are:

1) Should I change from SHA-1 to SHA-2 on my internal Root CA or change the web site's certificate is enough?

2) Today, what is the impact of Root CAs using SHA-2 in browsers? Is there any browser yet that doesn't support SHA-1? Some of our customer still uses old versions of IE.

3) Will browsers stop trust Root CAs that use SHA-1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Checking the root certificates of my browser I see that almost all
>   Root CAs are using SHA-1 or below.

**The signing algorithm used for the trusted root certificates is unimportant.**  Signatures are used to establish trust.  By definition, a trusted root certificate is one which you implicitly trust based on provenance (e.g., where it came from and how it got into your trusted root store - by the OS/browser installer, by Group Policy, etc).  The signature of the trusted root certificate is never verified against the signer (and they're generally self signed, of course).  Rather, signatures are used to verify *untrusted certificates* that are *handed to the browser on the fly* by the *not-yet-trusted server*.

***That being said......*** it is probably worth using a SHA-2 signed cert for your internal CA because people look at certificate chains and assume SHA-1 bad, SHA-2 good.  If you go with SHA-2, you won't have to deal with people asking you this very question :)

> 1) Should I change from SHA-1 to SHA-2 on my internal Root CA or
>   change the web site's certificate is enough?

It is not necessary to change the root certificate to SHA-2, but it may help avoid questions from users and auditors.

I would not go through the trouble of re-issuing existing certs; I would create a new SHA-2 root and use it for all future certificate signings.  That way the SHA-1 version of the root will go away over the next few years as your existing certificates expire.

> 2) Today, what is the impact of Root CAs using SHA-2 in browsers? Is
>   there any browser yet that doesn't support SHA-1? Some of our customer
>   still uses old versions of IE.

I assume you mean "browser [that doesn't yet] support SHA-2?"  Yes, there are still old versions of browsers out there that don't support SHA-2 ([nifty compatibility table](https://www.digicert.com/sha-2-compatibility.htm)), but if your users are running those, they should be forced off them for general reasons, not because of your root CA.

> 3) Will browsers stop trust Root CAs that use SHA-1?

I would not be surprised if that happens, *years* down the road, because of the "appearance of security" issue that I mention above.  But not quickly because, again, in technical terms, the browser doesn't use the signature on trusted root certificates.

Comment: Are you sure all existing certs would need to be re-issued? Isn't it possible to only re-issue the root CA cert, using SHA-2, and installing it into the browsers by replacing the old one and keeping all previously issued certs valid? (Even if it is a quite good practice to change private keys after some time)

Comment: That was a great answer. In fact was exactly the type of answer we were looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @JyodeLys you are correct, simply re-signing the root cert and re-distributing it will allow it to continue to be used.  Because it isn't necessary to make this an immediate change, and because the complexity of re-signing rather than migrating to a new one can be more confusing, I chose to list the other method.  But I think either one would work just fine.